# How to Fix Shiny App Local Browser Issue?

Tags: docker, shiny

I have a shiny app that works fine when I run the app through RStudio. Everything loads fine on http://127.0.0.1:xxxx, however I don't see the app when I click on "Open in Browser". Is this a generic issue that has a workaround? If you think the ui and server code is need, I can provide that.

I am trying to fix this above issue because I think this could be the reason that my docker image for this app is not showing up on http://localhost .

Here is the Dockerfile:

```
FROM r-base:3.5.0

# Install Ubuntu packages
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    sudo \
    gdebi-core \
    pandoc \
    pandoc-citeproc \
    libcurl4-gnutls-dev \
    libcairo2-dev/unstable \
    libxt-dev \
    libssl-dev 


# Add shiny user
RUN groupadd  shiny \
&& useradd --gid shiny --shell /bin/bash --create-home shiny



# Download and install ShinyServer
RUN wget --no-verbose https://download3.rstudio.org/ubuntu-14.04/x86_64/shiny-server-1.5.7.907-amd64.deb && \
    gdebi shiny-server-1.5.7.907-amd64.deb


# Install R packages that are required
RUN R -e "install.packages(c('Benchmarking', 'plotly', 'DT'), repos='http://cran.rstudio.com/')"
RUN R -e "install.packages('shiny', repos='https://cloud.r-project.org/')"

# Copy configuration files into the Docker image
COPY shiny-server.conf  /etc/shiny-server/shiny-server.conf
COPY /app /srv/shiny-server/

# Make the ShinyApp available at port 80
EXPOSE 80

# Copy further configuration files into the Docker image
COPY shiny-server.sh /usr/bin/shiny-server.sh

CMD ["/usr/bin/shiny-server.sh"]
```

When I run `docker run -p 80:80 myimage`, i don't get any error message, however I don't see any app on http://localhost. I even went ahead and added a new rule for network on VM Virtual Box, where the guest and host ports are 80, Host IP = 127.0.0.1, Guest IP = 192.168.99.100, and still app doesn't show up on localhost.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have a Dockerfile and a `docker-compose.yml` or `docker run` command that you can share?  It’d be helpful if you can describe the issue fairly concretely and provide a [mcve] showing what’s going on.

Comment: Hi David. I have the Dockerfile but don't have docker-compose.yml. Don't know how to get the yml file. Would the Dockerfile and `docker run` command be enough?

Comment: Yes (the `docker-compose.yml` in the end is just an alternate way of writing down the `docker run` commands).

Comment: I added the Dockerfile, and the only docker run command that I use `docker run -p 80:80 myimage`. I hope this provides enough information about the issue.

Comment: ...oh, are you using Docker Toolbox or Docker Machine?  You need to use the 192.168.99.100 address and not `localhost` in that case.

Comment: Yes, I am using Docker Toolbox. I just run the docker image and went to http://192.168.99.100 and it says "This site can't be reached." I am curious whether the issue is with Shiny app or docker setup. The Shiny app loads fine on desktop RStudio.